# Php fopen write in css file -> file empty

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

i have this following php code :

```
     $filename = '/front/style.css';
    $cssfile='#h1{font-size:12px}';
     if($id_file=fopen($filename, "w+"))
        {  
            echo'file exist';
         $id_file=fopen($filename, "w+");
         flock($id_file,1);
         fwrite($id_file,$cssfile); 
         flock($id_file,3);
         fclose($id_file);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "file don t exist";
        }
```

My file is empty but with space.
My file exist and it s writable.
I have nothing in my apache logs.
I m using Mamp with php 5.3.2.

Any ideas ?
Thx

Comment: What's wrong with this? What do you want us to do?

Comment: i don t know what wrong with this. It seems correct..If someone encounter the same problem...

Comment: Can you 100% ensure $cssfile is defined? Or do `var_dump($cssfile);` right before you do the fwrite ?

Comment: Do you actually have a `/front` directory in the  root of your file system? Remember that PHP's file operations are at the filesystem level and know nothing about your website's virtual structure. If your site's css file is actually at `/home/sites/example.com/html/front/style.css`, you're writing to a completely different file.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, i have a /front in the root, the path is an absolute path like this : /Users/myname/.../front/style.css

Comment: really??? I suggest you write into /tmp/style.css, and check again after re-run the code

Comment: @ajreal i follow advice from codaddict, it works now.

Comment: @adokora: that's not an absolute filesystem path. `/users/myname` is absolute filesystem, `/front/...` is absolute WEB root, which is almost always NOT directly mappable to the actual filesystem layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few mistakes I can see are:

1. You are using `fopen` to check if a file exists. That does not work. With the `w+` mode PHP will try to create the file if it does not exist. Use the `file_exits` function to check the existence of a file.
2. You are opening the same file twice.

Also use PHP constants(`LOCK_SH`, `LOCK_UN`) for the second argument of `flock`. That will make your program more readable.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Have you checked if its writing to a different directory than you expect? Check your path to see where it defaults to, or even just do a search for the file and see where else it turns up. getcwd() will show what the current working dir is.

Have you checked the return value of fwrite to see if the write is actually working? If fwrite is successful, then try read the file in the code using the same $id_file and see if there is anything there while the program is still running.

You are calling fopen twice. w+ truncates the file  and you are writing to the 2nd $id_file so my guess is that its being truncated when the 1st $id_file is being closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach if your file empty after using fopen w+ option.

```
// only read
$filename = '/path/to/blah.txt';
$myfile = fopen($filename, "r");
$mydata = fread($myfile, filesize($filename));
$mynewdata = $mydata + 'abc';
fclose($myfile);

// only write
$myfile = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $mynewdata);
fclose($myfile);
```